# How to disply array values in NSTableview in OSX App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

My viewController.xib having one button and tableview and i have some array values.If i click buttton array data will disply in tableview.
Is it possible with out using  applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: Follow this tutorial for the help

http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Displaying_Data_in_NSTableViews

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return exampleArray.count;
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return 50;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [exampleTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellWithSwitch"];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [exampleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

-(IBAction)exampleButtonAction:(id)sender
{
     exampleArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"example1",@"example2",@"example3",@"example4",nil];
     [exampleTableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Thak you .Iam asking that question for OSX App

Comment: You can follow this tutorial:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically/PopulatingView-TablesProgrammatically.html

Comment: How to connect or settings for connecting  NSTableView contoller to myviewController.xib.Please reply me